# A datasource inside a Viewmodel (observable) is used in a grid , trying to use same datasource but in a different grid(different sorting,filters )

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

so i have a **viewModel** and a **datasource** inside it .

(HRSelectorDataSource,kendoHRBaseGrid are custom widgets dont worry about that)

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        /* datasources */
        listDataSource: new kendo.ui.HRSelectorDataSource({
            ... options...
        }),
```

and i have the first **grid1** where i use my datasource just fine

```
    var grid1 = $("#grid").kendoHRBaseGrid({
            dataSource: viewModel.get("listDataSource")
                            ...
    }).data("kendoHRBaseGrid");
```

now im trying to use a second grid ( **grid2** ) that will get the same datasource(listDataSource) but it will have different sorting or filtering.

I tried to add some filtering in **grid2** but it changes the filtering also in grid1.

so for a solution i was thinking

**a)** to make a **copy of this datasource** so it can be used in **grid2**

which i dont know how to do it and i dont know if its best practise to just get the data from server again.

**b)** somehow to make the filtering on grid2 and not on datasource

**Has anyone any idea how to solve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get the data from the server again, you only need to get the data from the datasource. What you could do when you go to initialize your `kendoHRBaseGrid` widget is create a new instance of a datasource, but set the data equal to the data from the original datasource:

```js
var grid1 = $("#grid").kendoHRBaseGrid({
  dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: viewModel.get('listDataSource').data(),
    filter: { field: 'name', operator: 'startswith', value: 'foo' },
    sort: { field: 'name', dir: 'desc' }
  }),
  // etc...
}).data("kendoHRBaseGrid");
```

Now if your original datasource uses server-side filtering, paging, or sorting, then you would need to hit the server again. But if the datasource uses client-side operations then the example above should work.